# How can I allow the size of an ImageView to vary with an AnimationDrawable?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I plan to animate an explosion with an AnimationDrawable and I have frames saved of increasing sizes:

[image]

The problem is that I specify the ImageView size initially to `wrap_content`, so when I play the animation, the ImageView's size remains constant and the larger frames just skew down to match the original size.

How can I allow the ImageView to increase in size as the image increases while being animated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set any `View`'s width and height by assigning `LayoutParams` with the desired width/ height to that `View`. You can use e.g. a `ValueAnimator` and `ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener` to get something like an impulse generator and modify and re-set the `LayoutParams` repeatedly.

BUT in my opinion that's not the best way to go, and so I won't give the full particulars of this approach. Why do I think it is bad? Because by repeatedly changing the `View`'s boundaries you will cause at least the whole `ViewGroup` containing the `View` to go through a new [layout pass](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) every time you change the boundaries. This may be no problem on many devices, but all device owners will benefit from apps which don't unnecessarily drain the battery.

My suggestion is to use an `ImageView` which has the size of the biggest frame you wish to show. By keeping this `ImageView`'s size unchanged we enable the runtime to "concentrate" on re-drawing just the area covered by the `ImageView`, which will be much better for performance.

By setting the attribute `android:scaleType="center"` you will cause all frames to appear centered (and not scaled) in the `ImageView`, so I think this will give the desired effect.

If on the other hand your `ImageView` is not the only thing which has to be moved/ changed then I'd look into the [`Transition` framework.](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html)